# Problem facing fetching contacts from yahoo using open Social API

Tags: java, api, yahoo, opensocial

I was trying to get contact list from yahoo for POC. It was documented that the there is need to send a GET request to the URL with the user's ID and returns the contact list in XML format. I tried the same but facing the authentication message 401 from browser, normal console java application and from jsp too I guess I must try it using the open social API package. Can anybody please guide or suggest the solution for this problem if possible please post any code sample for any similar application in **JAVA** as I found most samples are unclear and in JSON only.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo recently released an SDK for accessing Yahoo Social services via Java:
http://developer.yahoo.net/blog/archives/2010/07/yos_sdk_for_java.html

Answer (score 0):

socialauth is a java library that allows importing contacts from Google, Yahoo, Hotmail and from other providers too.

http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/